# Can Monk's Unarmored Movement Improvement be used to run down a wall?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk

My player is asking me if he could use this ability to run his full movement speed down a vertical surface, and then have gravity kick in. So his fall damage if he were running down a cliff wouldn't start until after the first 120 feet of movement (if he dashes first) instead of starting from the top of the cliff.

Is this a viable use of this ability? I imagine the ability working like running on walls. Going straight up is fine. But straight down? Seems like it shouldn't work this way.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: If there's an answer that has helped you the most answer a question, then it's usually considered good manners to "accept" the answer (only one such answer can be "accepted", you tick the little green tick next to it). If there are answers missing the point, then you could specify that they are missing the point in the comments below them

Answer (score 13):

## RAW, yes, running down a vertical wall is a completely valid use of this class feature

The relevant text is as follows (emphasis mine):

> At 9th level, you gain the ability to **move along vertical surfaces** and across liquids on your turn without falling during your move.

This is clear cut; a monk can move along a vertical surface however they want, as long as they keep moving. Once they stop moving, they'll plummet, but until then they can run all around the wall, cliff, or other vertical surface.

As a DM, however, you are empowered to make rulings contrary to the published rules, or clarifying those rules, so if you think this should be different, make it so. You are advised to be cautious in this approach, however, because changing a player's character (for good or for ill) after the character is created is likely to be met poorly with the player and, possibly, the party.

Comment: Also remember that you can "flavor" that movement in a way that makes more logical sense for the mechanics. For example, rather than running down the wall, maybe the monk is able to slide down the wall for a certain distance, thereby breaking their fall partially.

Comment: In a previous edition (2e??), high level monks could fall an unlimited distance as long as they were within 10 feet of a wall. The flavor for it was basically them touching the wall and using friction to slow their fall.